# Google Sheets combining REDUCE & FILTER to compare and extract data from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, reduce

I have been struggling with a problem for a few weeks now and after trying to solve it myself I come cap in hand for help.
I have tried to use QUERY and ARRAYFORMULA and quite a few other formulas, but I can't crack it.

I have 3 workbooks that need to work together.

1. [Product Catalogue](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J_8v2biODyIwsV9f2F6gLnK0N-bR4Fsokrmd88PfxMg/edit#gid=0) - holds a list of each product type and the components that go into it (like a recipe).
2. [Schedule](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gvOZ_GuZx6HOLHQ7WwyIlFHrAihoNXz2ysZkublh7Fs/edit#gid=1198217965) - This sheet contains tabs for each product and then in each tab is a list of specific iterations of the product.
3. [Components Required](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1adBwjgUuXT4Ii6A3ywePV_M36LG-fk2GkjAkkGrWxFk/edit#gid=1931128866) - This sheet contains tabs for each component that we require. In each tab cell A1 contains the component number and each tab is named the same as the component number.

What I need to do is compare the Product Catalogue to the Schedule and populate the Components Required sheet tabs with the *specific iterations* from the schedule.

The data I am working with has many products and over 400 components and over 400 product iterations and the data is confidential.
So I have built some dummy sheets to replicate my challenge. Links above.

My solution has been focused on adding a formula to cell A3 of each Components Required tab, which looks at the component number (cell A1) and searches for this component number in the Product Catalogue. In most cases, it will find the component listed several times against several Products. Once it has found all the Products, it needs to look up those products in the Schedule and then import the full list of *specific iterations* from each of the products into row A of that Components Required tab.

In the Components Required sheet the first tab is an example of how I would like the data to look once imported, it has been manually copy/pasted by me to demonstrate the outcome.

Any help that anyone can offer would be gratefully recieved.

Thanks
Tim

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Thank you for your information. It seems I have some work to do to adapt my post.
I'll follow your suggestions ASAP. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that I was asking too much with my question.
However, I have worked hard on it and have come up with a solution, which may help others in the future.

I welcome feedback on the formula and also my method of answering my own question.

```
=REDUCE("Product Code", 
FILTER(importrange("1J_8v2biODyIwsV9f2F6gLnK0N-bR4Fsokrmd88PfxMg/edit#gid=0","Product Catalogue!$A$2:$A"),importrange("1J_8v2biODyIwsV9f2F6gLnK0N-bR4Fsokrmd88PfxMg/edit#gid=0","Product Catalogue!$B$2:$B") = INDIRECT("A1")), 
LAMBDA(a,c,   {a;importrange("1gvOZ_GuZx6HOLHQ7WwyIlFHrAihoNXz2ysZkublh7Fs/edit#gid=1198217965",c&"!A2:A"&COUNTA(importrange("1gvOZ_GuZx6HOLHQ7WwyIlFHrAihoNXz2ysZkublh7Fs/edit#gid=1198217965",c&"!A1:A")))}))
```

The resulting formula can be seen inside the [Components required](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1adBwjgUuXT4Ii6A3ywePV_M36LG-fk2GkjAkkGrWxFk/edit#gid=1176225385) spreadsheet in sheet C0001 cell A2

Thanks for the help I have received from everyone on the forum

Comment: @TheMaster your help with the REDUCE inspired me to find my solution. Thank you